# "На основании" или "из"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Мы разрабатываем систему ERP, и в некоторых документах делаем автозаполнение некоторый полей из других документов, отображая подсказку над полем: "Автозаполнение валюты из договора", "Автозаполнение суммы из документа прием на работу" и т. п., т. е. используем предлог "из".

Но наш дизайнер в макете написала формулировку так: "Автозаполнение на основании статьи затрат", "Автозаполнение на основании банка" (когда подтягиваются банковские реквизиты из карточки банка). Возникла дискуссия. Все считают что это нормально и что "на основании" читается нормально, но у меня возникает диссонанс: я понимаю смысл того, что происходит при автозаполнении, но этот предлог идет вразрез с тем, что считаю я. Я считаю, что использовать "на основании" тут неуместно, т. к. это больше подходит для "на основании федерального закона, постановления" и т. п., и что, если мы что-то достаем из чего-то, надо использовать "из".

Как правильно?

Comment: Ваш вопрос исправили, как мне кажется- с некоторым превышением полномочий, ибо теряется авторский стиль, а в чем-то и смысл. Если вы тоже недовольны такой правкой, можете откатить.

Comment: @behemothus Каким образом стиль, а в чём-то и смысл может заключаться в пропущенных и лишних запятых? Что конкретно из стиля и смысла пропало в результате правки?

Answer (score 1):

Ох... Из двух вариантов я бы предпочел "из". Но создавай этот макет я, скорее всего написал бы по-своему, каким-то еще способом (в зависимости от того, что на самом деле происходит и общего интерфейса приложения).)

Тут вопрос бы ваш понять адекватно, не то что ответ дать...
Если кратко, то оба варианта не нравятся, но это не вопрос русского языка как такового. Тут больше бухгалтерской и канцелярской условности, чем грамматики и стилистики.

Могу пояснит следующим образом.

**"Из"** в ваших конструкциях означает, видимо, что данные механически заполняются теми цифрами, какие есть по отсылке на документ, своего рода копипаста. Но такое понимание требует некоторой сноровки, для простого смертного оно неоднозначно.

**"На основании"** имеет свои проблемы. Оно предполагает, что документ содержит не сами данные, а лишь некие основания для их получения. Пример: *паспорт №123456789 выдан на основании заявления об утере паспорта №987654321*. Тут все гладко с точки зрения и смысла и русского языка. Но при этом в канцелярии (паспортном столе) напишут скорее всего *"выдан на основании паспорта №987654321."* Они так привыкли.
Так что тут сразу неоднозначность еще похлеще первой.

Решать в конечном счете - заказчику.

(+)====
@ЕгорСальков рассматривает как синоним "исходя из", но это не совсем правильно с точки зрения ситуации. Не "исходя из", а именно что из такого-то источника. Непосредственно из него. Кабы не это я бы с ним согласился.  Но вы можете понимать по-своему.

Comment: Ну да, я и имел в виду: исходя именно из такого-то источника, непосредственно из него. Вы, конечно, правы: в таких вопросах много бухгалтерской условности... Вы хотите сказать, что на бухгалтерском языке «исходя из» означает не отсылку к букве конкретного текста, а просто основанный на ней логический вывод?

Comment: @ЕгорСальков *бухгалтерском языке «исходя из» означает не отсылку к букве конкретного текста, а просто основанный на ней логический вывод?* - как раз наоборот. Или почти наоборот. На бухгалтерском - это вообще не отсылка как таковая. А просто указание "буквы" (чаще - цифры) и её источника. А вот на нормальном языке - это именно вывод.

Comment: Тогда «исходя из» — как раз то, что человеку нужно: отсылка к конкретной букве/цифре и её источнику. Нет?

Comment: @ЕгорСальков *Тогда «исходя из» — как раз то, что человеку нужно* - нет. Человеку нужна ***приемлемая в его среде*** и/или Заказчику формулировка. А тут можно только гадать.

Comment: То есть в его среде или для Заказчика «исходя из» может как раз означать вывод?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что здесь одного лишь предлога мало. Надо что-то добавить.

Может, так?
*Автозаполнение данными банка*. || Для процесса.
*Автозаполнение по данным банка*. || Для название действия.

"На основе" лучше, чем "на основании", потому что оно указывает на то, что составляет основу для автозаполнения. А "на основании" — это больше как разрешение (в словаре — право).

"Автозаполнение на основании банка" точно не подходит, потому что должен быть указан документ (основа для автозаполнения), а не банк.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что правильно понимаю, в каком смысле вы употребили выражение «если мы что-то достаём из чего-то», но если ваше «из» является сокращённой формой составного предлога «исходя из», то, пожалуй, возражаете вы напрасно: Толковый словарь Ефремовой считает эти конструкции синонимичными.

> **исходя́ из**
>
> *предл. с род.* [т. е. *предлог, употребляющийся с родительным падежом*]
>
> Употребляется при указании на основу, основание совершения какого-либо
> действия и соответствует по значению сл.: *на основании чего-либо, на
> основе чего-либо.*
>
> https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/172246/%D0%98%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F

Comment: у нас есть справочники (статей затрат, различных документов, справочник стран, регионов и банков и тд), в каждом справочнике есть ряд характеристик.

при создании документа мы заполняем поля, эти поля ссылки на справочник, например, для создания документа Списание с расчетного счета, мы должны заполнить договор и КА, а есть технические поля статья ддс, или валюта, которые заполняются автоматически.

Валюта тянется с договора, а статья ДДС из спр. Контрагенты.

Формулировка "автозаполнение статьи затрат на основании Контрагента" - мне не понятна, но "автозаполнение из контрагента" - ДА

Comment: А формулировка «автозаполнение исходя из Контрагента» понятна?

Comment: @Корбен *...мне не понятна, но "автозаполнение из контрагента" - ДА* В данной ситуации я бы использовал формулировку "из данных контрагента". Или "из справочника контрагентов". Но тут уж могут ваши коллеги заартачиться.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вот что я прочитала **про ERP систему**

*ERP система представляет собой набор модулей (или даже отдельных приложений). Каждый модуль управляет определенным процессом: бухгалтерским и налоговым учетом, производством, закупками, продажами, кадровыми процессами, поддержкой клиентов, CRM, складской логистикой и т.д. При этом ERP система охватывает основные процессы всех направлений деятельности предприятия.*

2. Исходя из информации, указанной в вопросе, я бы выбрала **предлог ИЗ**, например: ***автозаполнение цифрового массива (для валюты) из договора.***
3. Дело в том, что сочетание «на основании чего-либо» может предполагать  какие-то **промежуточные преобразования**, а не просто прямое копирование данных.  Соответственно, для прямого копирования больше подойдет предлог ИЗ.

Comment: Совет, как можно улучшить ваши ответы, чтобы они больше нравились всем вокруг: добавить конкретики и пояснения. Вот читаю и не понимаю... *Дело в том, что сочетание «на основании чего-либо» может предполагать какие-то промежуточные преобразования* — что за "промежуточные преобразования"? с чего вы взяли, что такое может быть? как это связано с "на основании"? Без этого этот пункт ни о чём, его можно удалить без ущерба. Представьте, что вы детям объясняете, только на взрослом языке. Рассчитывал, что вы предложите свой вариант, а не просто выберете из уже имеющихся.